# Extending the Unity Standard shader with an additional subshader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm applying a "burning" dissolve shader to an object which uses the Standard shader already. Because I need the Standard shader for better lighting, etc, I looked into how to use them "both" or how to extend the standard shader.

According to the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html) I can define which lighting mode I want to use in the `pragma` so I used `Standard`. That must not work the way I thought, because I see none of the lighting I do when using the standard shader directly.

I'm using the burning dissolve shader from [Harry Alisavakis](http://halisavakis.com/my-take-on-shaders-dissolve-shader/)

```
Shader "Custom/BurnDissolve" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _SliceGuide("Slice Guide (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _SliceAmount("Slice Amount", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0

        _BurnSize("Burn Size", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.15
        _BurnRamp("Burn Ramp (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BurnColor("Burn Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

        _EmissionAmount("Emission amount", float) = 2.0
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200
        Cull Off
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard

        fixed4 _Color;
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _SliceGuide;
        sampler2D _BumpMap;
        sampler2D _BurnRamp;
        fixed4 _BurnColor;
        float _BurnSize;
        float _SliceAmount;
        float _EmissionAmount;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            half test = tex2D(_SliceGuide, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb - _SliceAmount;
            clip(test);

            if (test < _BurnSize && _SliceAmount > 0) {
                o.Emission = tex2D(_BurnRamp, float2(test * (1 / _BurnSize), 0)) * _BurnColor * _EmissionAmount;
            }

            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Standard"
}
```

I also tried adding this as another subshader to a copy of the Standard shader source, but I wasn't able to get it working there. If I put it before the others, it works as if it was alone, if I put it after, the standard shader works like if it was alone.

I'm still new to shaders so I'm sure I'm misunderstanding this. How can I get the dissolve shader to apply as well the standard shader, without hopefully having to manually rewrite stuff.

Per request, here are the images I'm using (which were originally provided by the linked dissolve shader article).

As `_SliceGuide`:

[image]

As `_BurnRamp`:

[image]

Using the `#prama target 3.0` and `o.Smoothness = 0.5f` changes Shaman mentioned, I get this:

[image]

Which is definitely better, but I guess there are effects Standard is giving me because here's how Standard by itself looks:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the textures that you are using in your shader.

Comment: I haven't modified them from the article I linked, but added them to the article for reference.

Comment: So basically you just want your shader to match the standard shader in terms of lighting?

Comment: Yes. I use the standard shader (default config). I'm pretty sure it's lighting only but the standard shader is a complex beast. I haven't changed the defaults though. Ideally, I'd like the standard shader to apply everything it needs to, and the dissolve shader would apply after that. I don't need the dissolve/burn effect affected by lighting, though it wouldn't be an issue if it were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard shader uses **shader model 3.0 target**, to get nicer looking lighting.
So you need add this: `#pragma target 3.0`.
Also Standard shader's default config has its smoothness set to 0.5 whereas in your shader's case it's set to 0, so in order to make the shaders match in terms of lighting, you have to add following line: `o.Smoothness = 0.5f;`.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me closer. There seems to be a level of detail Standard has that I'm still missing. I don't know if this is because of lighting alone? I've updated my question with screen shots.

Comment: Toying around, I'm guessing that it's because the standard shader uses a normal map for this asteroid, but the burn dissolve doesn't, it simply uses the standard lighting model?

Comment: I think that's the case! You could add a normal map to your shader and see if it matches the Standard shader.

Comment: That was it, funny enough my source already had an entry for it (`sampler2D _BumpMap;`) but it wasn't used anywhere. I snagged the `o.Normal` example from the unity docs "writing surface shaders" and it working perfectly. Thanks!